# What values for the global state variables does geth use for estimateGas?

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, gas-estimate

What values for the global state variables does geth use for estimateGas?

For example, block.timestamp.

Comment: What do you mean? For a real estimation geth executes the contract, accessing contracts, storage, latest mined block, etc.

Comment: So the values used are from the latest block?